# Position of Slider's item h1 variable, h2 static overlap the first

Tags: html, css

I have an slider item's with an image, h1 and h2.I'm having problems with the position of h1 and h2 on mobile phones. The h2 has position absolute, so when the h1 has bigger text, the h2 doesn't move down, instead it he overlap the h1.

I have a live example so I think is better for you to [see it](http://residenciarucab.es/rucab/index.php).

Scroll to the last slider of the page and see in mobile version.

```
  <div class="container" style="height: 100%;">
  <div class="row">

      <div id="carouselExampleControls3" class="carousel slide test-slider">
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="banner col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-xl-12 mx-auto">
            <img alt="Bootstrap Image Preview"  src="img/testimonios/_MG_6541-copia.jpg"/>

     <div> <h1 class="test-h1">"ESTOY CON MIS AMIGOS Y SIENTO LIBERTAD"</h1><h2><span>JACOBO CARRASCO</span>,<br> MADRID</h2>
        </div></div>
    </div>

</div>    </div>

    <div class="carousel-item">
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="banner col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-xl-12 mx-auto">
            <img alt="Bootstrap Image Preview"  src="img/testimonios/_MG_6522-copia.jpg"/>

      <div><h1 class="test-h1 gran-parrafo">"LO MEJOR SON LOS RATITOS QUE PASAMOS EN EL CHILL OUT"</h1><h2><span>LAURA LANDA</span>,<br> LA RIOJA</h2>
        </div></div>
    </div>

</div>    </div>

    <div class="carousel-item">
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="banner col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-xl-12 mx-auto">
            <img alt="Bootstrap Image Preview"  src="img/testimonios/_MG_6548-copia.jpg"/>

      <div><h1 class="test-h1">"LA RUCAB ES PERFECTA PARA COMBINAR ESTUDIOS Y OCIO"</h1><h2><span>ALEJANDRO ÁLVAREZ</span>,<br> ALMENDRALEJO</h2>
        </div></div>
    </div>

</div>    </div>

    <div class="carousel-item">
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="banner col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-xl-12 mx-auto">
            <img alt="Bootstrap Image Preview"  src="img/testimonios/_MG_6501-copia.jpg"/>

      <div><h1 class="test-h1 gran-parrafo">"ES COMO ESTAR EN CASA CON UN MONTÓN DE AMIGOS Y COSAS QUE HACER"</h1><h2 class="gran-parrafo-h2"><span>MARTA MATEO</span>,<br> CÁCERES</h2>
        </div></div>
    </div>

</div>    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="banner col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-xl-12 mx-auto">
            <img alt="Bootstrap Image Preview"  src="img/testimonios/_MG_6512-copia.jpg"/>

      <div><h1 class="test-h1 gran-parrafo">"UN SITIO CAPAZ DE ENCONTRAR Y SACAR LO MEJOR DE CADA UNO"</h1><h2 class="gran-parrafo-h2"><span>CARMEN DE PEDRO</span>,<br> CÁCERES</h2>
        </div></div>
    </div>

</div>    </div>
</div>
      </div>
```

I paste the screenshot of all the item's. See that when the pink text is bigger the h2 overlap it:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

[image]

EDIT:

WITH THE ANSWER TWEAKS:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: your live example works fine for me. where did you get the screenshot?

Comment: I used my Chrome Dev tools with the iphone 5 size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your `h2` below your image is positioned absolutely below the image. Right now your structure looks like this:

```
<div class="banner">
  <img alt="bootstrap Image Preview" src="img/testimonios/_MG_6512-copia.jpg">
  <div>
    <h1 class="test-h1 gran-parrafo">UN SITIO CAPAZ DE ENCONTRAR Y SACAR LO MEJOR DE CADA UNO</h1>
    <h2 class="gran-parrafo-h2">Carmen de Pedro</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

And your CSS:

```
.banner .gran-parrafo-h2 {
    font-size: 1.2em;
    font-weight: 500;
    right: 0px !important;
    width: 100% !important;
    position: absolute !important;
    text-align: center;
}
```

First thing is to get rid of the absolute positioning of the `h2` element but due to the CSS structure you use you will need to change several rules in parts.

You will need to tweak the rules yourself but here is a recommendation that works at least in my Developer tools:

```
.banner div {
  position: relative; /* <-- remove */
  right: 0px !important; /* <-- remove */
  bottom: 65px; /* <-- remove */
}
.banner img {
    padding-bottom: 20px !important; /* was: 80px */   
}

.banner h1 {
  bottom: 65px !important; /* <-- remove */
}
.banner h2 {
  position: relative;
  top: 0; /* <-- remove */  
  right: 0px !important; /* <-- remove */
}
```

In general you can remove all of the `position: relative;` and `position: absolute;` rules and just use the element's native display types. As you have to different display version - desktop browser and mobile visitor - you should add your changed CSS for the mobile version inside a media-query block for mobile devices, otherwise your desktop version will be cluttered.

**Preview:**

This was taken in an emulated browser window, you will also need to check how to change the image width to fit your visitor's device, otherwise not only the image but also the text will be displayed outside of the browser window.

[image: Preview]

Comment: I tried to apply your tweaks but look' how it shows. I updated the question with the screenshoot of your tweak.

Comment: @PedroCorcheroMurga thanks for accepting my answer :). I think you hadn't removed the `position: absolute;` from `.banner img` which caused the overlap. But great to see you managed to change it. Btw., the web page really looks nice, well done!